# "Второй открытый конкурс" — с прописной или строчной буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Объявлен второй открытый конкурс "Образцовая семья — 2015".

*Второй* — с прописной или строчной?

Comment: А почему он назван "вторым"? В 2015 году был и первый? ===

Comment: Видимо, был еще раньше.

Answer (score 1):

> Объявлен второй открытый конкурс "Образцовая семья — 2015".

Я бы оставил в таком виде. Или бы вообще удалил слово "второй". Ведь предыдущий конкурс, скорее всего, имел название "Образцовая семья — 2014",  а не "Образцовая семья — 2015".

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему ''второй" с прописной...